# UIScrollView with dynamic Footer

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, storyboard, scrollview

i have a Label and a ContainerView (With a Label and Switch as childs) in a ScrollView.
I want that my ContainerView has a Padding to the Label Bottom but if the Label
has too much height (that it needs to get scrolled) the footer should be sticked to the bottom of the Screen (should not get scrolled). Is it possible to do it with AutoLayout?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you laying this out in Storyboard? or via code?

Comment: i want to layout with storyboard but i dont know if its possible with autolayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this...

I'm going to recommend you place your "switch container view" ***outside*** the scroll view, pinned to the scroll view's bottom. When the content of the scroll view (the multi-line label) changes height, we'll change the height of the scroll view -- *until the switch container reaches the bottom of the view* (the safe-area bottom).

Here's how it looks in Storyboard:

[image]

The multi-line label has a cyan background, and the switch container view has a yellow background.

Note that we have constrained the scroll view's Height to the Height of the multi-line label, but set the Priority to `750 (High)`. By changing it from Required to High, we're telling auto-layout to break that constraint if needed. That is, when it gets too tall for the available space.

Note also that the Bottom constraint on the switch container view is set to `>= 0`. When we add text to the multi-line label, it will cause the scroll view to grow in height *pushing the container view down* ... but only until it hits the bottom of the view (safe-area).

The only thing we don't see here - but it's important - is that we set `Vertical Content Compression Resistance` to `1000 (Required)` for both the multi-line label and the Switch.

Here is the source to this storyboard so you can inspect it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17506" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="XCt-Hc-wQm">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17505"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Scroll Footer View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Caf-Eb-sIu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="XCt-Hc-wQm" customClass="ScrollFooterViewController" customModule="DelMe" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="dUm-Xz-ZMW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="USX-Ck-yG1">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="21.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" verticalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lwg-yg-39D">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="21.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" secondItem="lwg-yg-39D" secondAttribute="height" priority="750" id="76J-30-uTn"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="lwg-yg-39D" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ZIz-K9-t2b" secondAttribute="trailing" id="GCE-Kl-AnT"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="lwg-yg-39D" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ZIz-K9-t2b" secondAttribute="leading" id="KKY-k0-5P6"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="lwg-yg-39D" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZIz-K9-t2b" secondAttribute="top" id="MY4-LC-VHJ"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="lwg-yg-39D" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="ZIz-K9-t2b" secondAttribute="bottom" id="dnk-39-RlU"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="lwg-yg-39D" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="PfO-IK-xkv" secondAttribute="width" id="zrQ-RH-rly"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="ZIz-K9-t2b"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="PfO-IK-xkv"/>
                            </scrollView>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Njo-Q9-KiY" userLabel="ContainerView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="21.5" width="375" height="47"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vUU-Ps-Crk" userLabel="SwitchLabel">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="13" width="42" height="21"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" verticalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="24L-2e-H7p">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="318" y="8" width="51" height="31"/>
                                    </switch>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="vUU-Ps-Crk" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="24L-2e-H7p" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Dwk-0c-XGq"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="24L-2e-H7p" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Vuj-Vf-Ubm"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="vUU-Ps-Crk" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Njo-Q9-KiY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="VzC-He-6eA"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="24L-2e-H7p" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Njo-Q9-KiY" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="xVS-9o-J0n"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="24L-2e-H7p" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="yR9-XP-FQq"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="y57-Pg-ijO"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="y57-Pg-ijO" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Njo-Q9-KiY" secondAttribute="trailing" id="7PH-bB-Xu1"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="USX-Ck-yG1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y57-Pg-ijO" secondAttribute="top" id="RRh-cW-cdn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="y57-Pg-ijO" firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Njo-Q9-KiY" secondAttribute="bottom" id="ZhG-3Y-WiX"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Njo-Q9-KiY" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="y57-Pg-ijO" secondAttribute="leading" id="aj2-fS-rab"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Njo-Q9-KiY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="USX-Ck-yG1" secondAttribute="bottom" id="eeo-Zi-yar"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="USX-Ck-yG1" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="y57-Pg-ijO" secondAttribute="trailing" id="iK0-ax-YU6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="USX-Ck-yG1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="y57-Pg-ijO" secondAttribute="leading" id="lMU-A2-QsG"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="multiLineLabel" destination="lwg-yg-39D" id="huD-0B-amT"/>
                        <outlet property="scrollView" destination="USX-Ck-yG1" id="2c5-7h-7Ii"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="cjI-ra-ksU" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1586.4000000000001" y="266.71664167916043"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

and some example code to demonstrate:

```
class ScrollFooterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var multiLineLabel: UILabel!
    
    var numLines: Int = 0
    var addLine: Bool = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add a tap recognizer...
        //  each time we tap the view, we'll add text from the sample text array
        //  until we reach the end of the array
        //  then, each tap will remove text until we reach 1
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.updateMultilineLabel))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
        // init the multiline label text
        updateMultilineLabel()
    }
    
    @objc func updateMultilineLabel() -> Void {
        // are we adding or removing text?
        if addLine == true {
            numLines += 1
        } else {
            numLines -= 1
            // keep at least 1 line of text
            numLines = max(numLines, 1)
        }
        
        // generate string with numLines of text from sample text array
        let s = sampleText[0..<numLines].joined(separator: "\n\n")
        
        // set text of multiline label
        multiLineLabel.text = s
        
        // auto-scroll to the bottom
        scrollToBottom(scrollView)
        
        // if we're at the end of the sample text array, switch from adding to removing
        if numLines == sampleText.count {
            addLine = false
        }
        // if we're at 1, switch from removing to adding
        if numLines == 1 {
            addLine = true
        }
    }
    
    func scrollToBottom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Void {
        // set content offset after 0.01 seconds (to make sure it runs after the label has updated its frame)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01, execute: {
            let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom)
            if(bottomOffset.y > 0) {
                scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
            }
        })
    }
    
    let sampleText: [String] = [
        "UILabel\n\nA label can contain an arbitrary amount of text, but UILabel may shrink, wrap, or truncate the text, depending on the size of the bounding rectangle and properties you set. You can control the font, text color, alignment, highlighting, and shadowing of the text in the label.",
        "UIButton\n\nYou can set the title, image, and other appearance properties of a button. In addition, you can specify a different appearance for each button state.",
        "UISegmentedControl\n\nThe segments can represent single or multiple selection, or a list of commands.\n\nEach segment can display text or an image, but not both.",
        "UITextField\n\nDisplays a rounded rectangle that can contain editable text. When a user taps a text field, a keyboard appears; when a user taps Return in the keyboard, the keyboard disappears and the text field can handle the input in an application-specific way. UITextField supports overlay views to display additional information, such as a bookmarks icon. UITextField also provides a clear text control a user taps to erase the contents of the text field.",
        "UISlider\n\nUISlider displays a horizontal bar, called a track, that represents a range of values. The current value is shown by the position of an indicator, or thumb. A user selects a value by sliding the thumb along the track. You can customize the appearance of both the track and the thumb.",
        "UISwitch\n\nDisplays an element that shows the user the boolean state of a given value.  By tapping the control, the state can be toggled.",
    ]
    
}
```

The code has a "sample text" array... Each time you tap the screen, more text will be adde to the multi-line label, until we reach the end of the array, at which point each tap will remove some of the text.

The result looks like this:

[image]

with a little more text, but not enough to require scrolling:

[image]

and with enough text that we'll need scrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my previous project, Here is the code

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewHeightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let labelHeight = self.textLabel.frame.size.height + 60
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 100
        self.scrollViewHeightConstraints.constant = min(screenHeight, labelHeight)
    }
```

constants 60 and 100 can be changes based on your view.